# Cordova IOS deployment

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, wkwebview

Please I need help to successfully migrate from **UIWebview to WKWebview** as Apple no longer accepts applications that make reference to **UIWebView**.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7T3x.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Cordova guide to upgrade: https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/03/18/wkwebviewonly.html